# Can a druid intentionally harm himself to gain balance?

Tags: druid, dungeon-world

The Druid advanced move Balance reads:

> When you deal damage, take 1 balance. When you touch someone and channel the spirits of life you may spend balance. For each balance spent, heal 1d4 HP.

Is it possible to intentionally deal damage to yourself? If so, could you do that to gain balance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fiction first. Ask questions and use the answers.

1. Ask what they're doing.

   > I'm stabbing myself so I can heal someone.
2. Ask how that works in the fiction. If they come up with something that the group finds interesting and plausible in the fiction already established, let them do it.  If not, say something along the lines of “It doesn't sound like your magic works that way.”

Answer (score 14):

Page 21 of the rulebook says:

> Dealing damage means you roll the damage dice for your class; sometimes your weapon will add or subtract damage too.

So the question becomes "Can a Druid intentionally harm themselves in order to roll their damage dice?".

There isn't a basic move which would trigger a damage dice roll (Hack and Slash, for instance, says "When you attack an enemy in melee" and Volley says "When you take aim and shoot at an enemy at range").

So, *not unless the DM created / approved a custom move that made it possible*. They probably should in order to follow the principle of "Begin and end with the fiction", but that would need begin with the player narratively justifying it.

Comment: That seems… constricting? To be honest, I'm more of an *Apocalypse World*/*Monster of the Week* guy, but in those games (that run off the same engine), a PC can totally just say, "I stab myself," and suffer the consequences. Is such a thing literally *impossible* in *DungeonWorld* without the MC's permission?

Comment: @HeyICanChan — The DM's principles say "Begin and end with the  fiction". If they stab themselves, they stab themselves and should suffer the consequences. They might lose hit points, but that isn't the same as triggering "dealing damage" which is a specific mechanic. (And that does need the DM's permission, because they arbitrate the mechanics, but they would be betraying the principles if they didn't follow through the logical effects of what happened in the fiction).

Comment: Cool enough. Nonetheless, I struggle to see how the fiction generally *can* support the Balance move when the druid's battling a monster yet *can't* support the move when the druid deliberately injures himself ("Balance, like the honey badger, just don't care," spake the druid sagely). I mean, I wouldn't fight the MC over the call or nothin'—I was just surprised.

Comment: It sounds cool enough that you get to roll your damage die to gain a balance, which you can use to heal another. And since your damage die is a d6, it wouldn't really be able to exploit it anyway.

Comment: @Erik And the idea of self-blood-sacrifice to fuel magic has a long tradition.

Comment: "Dealing damage" isn't a specific mechanic that can be "triggered". It's not a move, it doesn't engage the move rules that describe how moves trigger, and triggering isn't a mechanic/concept outside how moves trigger. That quote just explains how to resolve moves that say to deal damage; that's causally the opposite of the situation. This is misinterpreting how the mechanics get involved in this fiction situation. (I'm ignoring the GM move for dealing damage, because that's not what's being quoted and works even more differently.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it is acceptable. Creative, but acceptable.

While it is true that **Basic Moves** does not contain any such thing as **Harm Yourself**, and **Hack and Slash** explicitly talks about attacking *an enemy*, note that **Hack and Slash** *also* says that it applies only for a *prepared* enemy.

It says if you attack an enemy who is unaware of you attacking or restrained and helpless...

> You just deal your damage or murder them outright, depending on the situation. Nasty stuff.

Let's see if there is a **Murder Helpless Enemy** move. Nope, no such thing. However, the rules explicitly say that's something you can do. Thus, concequentially, I do not see any objection to inflicting damage on yourself in the same way, e.g. by using your dagger seppuku-style or such, and apply damage on yourself right away — without subtracting armour, obviously. I'd say d4 ("bruises and scrapes at worst") would be a bit tame, but d6 would be appropriate ("spills blood").

This might even make sense lore-wise if you see it as a sacrifice which you use for "paying" for the healing.